# Adobe Flex, check for server error on file download?

Tags: apache-flex, pdf

I'd like to have Flex trigger the browser to download a PDF file from a server, but if anything goes wrong with the script that generates the file I want to be able to throw a meaningful error from Flex.  Is it at all possible to try to open the URL in Flex first and check the response's HTTP status or Content-Type, then if it's a PDF file and not an error pass it up to the browser to display the "Save File..." dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URLRequest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) and [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) classes to send the request. Then you'll be able to catch an error.